# IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am using `IdentityServer4-2.0.0-preview2` and `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework-1.0.1` with Visual Studio 2017 Preview. I got an Exception as below:

> System.TypeLoadException:“Method 'GetAllResourcesAsync' in type
>   'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Stores.ResourceStore' from assembly
>   'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.”

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCookieAuthentication();
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
    services.AddDbContext<EntityLibrary.Models.ExportOMSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)); 
    var service_builder = services.AddIdentityServer();  
    service_builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential(); 
    service_builder.AddConfigurationStore(builder =>builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    service_builder.AddOperationalStore(builder =>builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
    service_builder.Services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The EF nuget is not working on asp net core 2 righ now. You can try to build from source yourself.